# Boost RegEx: Specific Question

Tags: c++, regex, boost-regex

I am trying to use this expression:

```
Expression:  "\w{1,}\s*?\-\-(\>)?\s*?\w{1,}"
```

Keep in mind I am escaping the \ with a second \ in my code.

When searching in the strings below. I think I am close, but no cigar. I want the expression above to be able to find matches in the text below. Where am I going wrong?

```
Text:        "AB --> CD"
Text:        "AB --> Z"
Text:        "A --> 123d"
etc.
```

Resources Used:

1. http://www.solarix.ru/for_developers/api/regex-en.html
2. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/introduction_and_overview.html
3. http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

---

**UPDATE**

The comment helped me. I would still like to see people post on my thread, for record keeping purposes, regex sites that have helped them master regex. Anyways my code (mostly copied from the boost website) is.

```
/* All captures from a regular expression */
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

/* Compiled with g++ -o regex_tut -lboost_regex -Wall ./regex_tut.cpp */

void print_captures(const std::string& regx, const std::string& text)
{
   boost::regex e(regx);
   boost::smatch what;
   std::cout << "Expression:  \"" << regx << "\"\n";
   std::cout << "Text:        \"" << text << "\"\n";
   if(boost::regex_match(text, what, e, boost::match_extra))
   {
      unsigned i;
      std::cout << "** Match found **\n   Sub-Expressions:\n";
      for(i = 0; i < what.size(); ++i) {
         std::cout << "      $" << i << " = \"" << what[i] << "\"\n";
      }
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "** No Match found **\n";
   }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[ ])
{
   print_captures("^\\w+\\s*-->?\\s*\\w+\\s*(\\(\\d+\\))?", "AB --> CD (12)" );
   return 0;
}
```

Seems to work. Please though so I can accept an answer post your favorite site up and give a newb a few pointers =).

Comment: Not a solution, but you can simplify your regex significantly: `\w+\s*-->?\s*\w+`

Comment: Good point the *? was redundant. I thought '-' and '>' were reserved characters and must be escaped. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i understood your question correctly, but if you want your regex to match for example `AB` and `CD` in `"AB --> CD"` you can use the following regex:

```
Expression:  "(\w+)\s*-->?\s*(\w+)"
```